# VOLATILE | IMMUTABLE behavior in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to understand the behavior of **VOLATILE** and **IMMUTABLE** keywords while we use during Procedure creation

As per the documentation, I have understood the theory

[image]

But I am trying to understand how these two keywords are behaving practically.

I have tried following examples

Example - **IMMUTABLE**

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE HELLO_WORLD()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
IMMUTABLE
AS
    $$
        var sql_command = 
     "select id, name from emp";
    try {
        var stmt = snowflake.execute (
            {sqlText: sql_command}
            );
         var a = []
         while (stmt.next()){
            a.push(stmt.getColumnValue(1))
         }
        return a;   
        }
    catch (err)  {
        return "Failed: " + err;  
        }
        
    $$;
    
CALL HELLO_WORLD();
```

Example - **VOLATILE**

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE HELLO_WORLD()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
VOLATILE
AS
    $$
        var sql_command = 
     "select id, name from emp";
    try {
        var stmt = snowflake.execute (
            {sqlText: sql_command}
            );
         var a = []
         while (stmt.next()){
            a.push(stmt.getColumnValue(1))
         }
        return a;   
        }
    catch (err)  {
        return "Failed: " + err;  
        }
        
    $$;
    
CALL HELLO_WORLD();
```

Both returns same output

```
[ 3, 2, 1 ]
```

Can anyone explain with any different example please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the difference is easier to understand with a UDF (instead of a stored procedure, but the semantics are the same):

```sql
create or replace function x(a string)
returns float 
language javascript
immutable  -- replace with volatile
as '
return Math.random();
';

select x('1')
from table(generator(rowcount => 5))
```

When the function is immutable: The select returns 5 identical random numbers.

When the function is volatile: The select returns 5 different random numbers.

Perhaps the documentation for the stored procedures should say "The procedure might return different values for the same input" instead of "The procedure might return different values for different rows".

Comment: Is the "immutable" indicator that query returns the same result for the same input between different calls(separate SELECTs) or only in case of single call?  Here if we run query twice we will get 5 the same values but different each time. To rephrase the question, how to mark a function to be safe to be used for result cache?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I've wondered about that too - the best for UDFs I've thought of is having the UDF have a global cache, but that only works when Snowflake re-uses the JS VM between calls.

Comment: (the biggest difference is between "Snowflake promises to use the cache" vs "Snowflake could choose to cache", which is the current promise with IMMUTABLE)